# OAuth request redirects to admin dashboard after login shopify

Tags: oauth, shopify, shopify-app

I have created a shopify application to read store data like category name, product name etc. Following this guideline https://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth

I have written script in python to make OAUTH request to install my application in shopify store. I am using the api key, secret key during OAuth request and also set the app url, whitelisted redirection url in my application in partner dashboard.
Here 2 cases happen:

1. the first case is when store owner is logged into the store OAuth request is granted and redirects to application installation page, and after installation redirects to redirect_url passed with OAuth request URL.
2. the 2nd case is when store owner is not logged into store OAuth request redirects to store login page and after login page redirects to admin dashboard of the store. does not redirect to application installation page.

No problem with the first case. I have been trying to solve the 2nd case. I want to redirect to application installation page after logged into the store.

Besides me other shopify developers are facing this problem. here are 2 other links of unanswered same question in shopify discussion forum.

https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/oauth-flow-for-non-logged-in-users-526732

https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apps/t/oauth-error-whitelisted-url-if-user-is-not-logged-in-516603

what I have tried:

I am trying to do it in django. here is the code in which I am trying to redirect user to shopify store for authorization.

```js
def redirect_to_shopify_store(request):
    redirect_url = "https://" + store_name + ".myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id=" + api_key

    redirect_url += "&scope=read_orders, write_checkouts, read_themes, write_themes, read_products, write_products, unauthenticated_read_product_listings, read_product_listings, read_collection_listings"

    redirect_url += "&redirect_uri=" + python_app_base_url + "/get_shopify_access_token/"

    redirect(redirect_url)
```

and here is the code I am trying to receive the shopify access token:

```js
def get_shopify_access_token(request):
    code = request.GET.get('code')
    client_id = shopify_config['client_id']

    request_url = "https://{store_name}.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token?client_id={client_id}".format(
    store_name=store_name, client_id=client_id
    )

    request_url += "&client_secret=" + shopify_config['client_secret']
    request_url += "&code=" + code

    response = requests.post(request_url)

    shopify_access_token = response.json()['access_token']

    print("shopify_access_token")
    print(shopify_access_token)

    redirect('success_page_url')
```

If I redirect like the following URL

```js
https://{store_name}.myshopify.com/admin/auth/login?redirect=oauth/authorize?client_id, access_scope
```

I get access_scope missing error and get redirected to following URL:

```js
https://{store_name}.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id
```

could not identify the reason for missing accsess_scope param.

Any help from shopify experts will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Not sure if this is helpful or not but here is my SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212290/is-it-possible-to-provide-a-redirect-url-to-shopify-com-login