# Is it possible to provide a `redirect url` to shopify.com/login?

Tags: shopify

Does Shopify have a mechanism to supply a redirect URL on store owner login at https://shopify.com/login. Note, this is not customer login, but store owner.

Mailchimp provides this functionality with a `redirect_uri` query string parameter. In the example below, after logging in, Mailchimp will redirect the user to https://somesite.com:

```
https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=1234567890&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fsomesite.com
```

Answer (score -2):

It sounds a little confusing. First of all. You seem to be concerned about whether a customer at a Shopify store (someone with an account to buy stuff and checkout) is logged in? Why? What on earth does that have to do with your App?

If you are truly concerned about that, your Shopify App, installed in the Shopify store, can accept a secure callback with the logged in customer, and you can use the API to get their details.

So there cannot be an answer to your question in my opinion, because your use case seems really mixed up in your explanation. Perhaps you can draw some boxes, connect them with arrows, publish that somewhere public, and start a discussion from there.

Comment: Nothing to do with customers. Shopify store owners. Just trying to reduce the amount of work they have to do. They're not always technical and don't always understand what their store URL is.

Comment: Well, touché then. Your question is not technically correct by a long shot either. If you choose to stray from Standard Shopify, letting merchants install your App from App Store versus you trying to get them in some other way, you better have your i's dotted and t's crossed. 

Try rewriting your question with correct terms, URL's and descriptions, and maybe someone will help you. Without that, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Dave. I re-worded the question making it much more concise and clear IMO. We're not straying from anything "standard". You can create "unlisted" apps for Shopify that can't be installed via the Shopify app store. The installation form is hosted on your own servers. The example code provided by Shopify has the user enter their `*.my-shopify.com` domain name, we're trying to do that for them automatically by redirecting them to our form with that field populated, after they log in to Shopify. Because, they have to be logged in to Shopify to install your app.

Comment: I do that all the time. I have/had 100+ Apps that never saw the light of day in the App store. You put up a form stolen from Shopify that mimics their App login. It asks for the shop name. You POST that to your App. Your App now redirects to the oAuth flow, and IF they are not logged into their shop, Shopify prompts them to login, and the oAuth flow continues.